# How to support special characters in text field?

Tags: theme-options

When i put special characters in text field on wordpress themes option then it's gonna add some slash characters Like if I put

```
It's
```

then its show

```
It\'s.
```

How i solve that?

Comment: are you trying to add the characters to a word in a php file?

Comment: No, I'm trying on themes option panel. Maybe this option panel does not sanitize special characters.

Comment: Can you screenshot it? I cant picture your dillema.

Comment: How do you save the options? Add the code to your question.

Comment: I'm using http://demo.truethemes.net/CodeCanyon-Pro-Panel/index.html

Comment: If i write this symbol (') then its added slash(/)
So i want if i write that symbol then not added slashes.

Comment: As toscho asked, please add your code to the question so that we can see how you save (and maybe before that _alter_) the text. Anyway, it seems that the options run through `addslashes` or something similar, so you could just it with `stripslashes` when outputting the text.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress always adds slash before quotes as the first step in processing input. You should strip those slashes before saving data into the DB. use `stripslashes` for strings or `stripslashes_deep` in case you are handling arrays.

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape the apostrophe yourself. Two ways to escape apostrophes is to do this:

```
It"'"s
```

Or this:

```
It\'s
```

If you do not escape them yourself, you likely end up with the problem you're having now. So try one of these methods in your options panel text box and see if that answers your question.